# Displaying JSON string in HTML via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, iframe

**(Question at the very end)** I'm making an api call to ebay and get a JSON file. One of the value fields of this JSON is html code written in plain text. I need to get this and embed it in an iframe . Now, this entire code is dynamically generated in javascript based on button clicks on the screen. My problem is that the code I write does not completely display the executed html raw text code.

JSON string example

```
"<font rwr=\"1\" size=\"4\" style=\"font-family:Arial\"><font rwr=\"1\" size=\"4\" style=\"font-family:Arial\"><font rwr=\"1\" size=\"4\" style=\"font-family:Arial\"><font rwr=\"1\" size=\"4\" style=\"font-family:Arial\"><font rwr=\"1\" style=\"font-family: Arial;\"><font rwr=\"1\" style=\"font-family: Arial;\"><div style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"><br><div style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"><font face=\"Georgia\"><b style=\"font-size: 14pt;\">A Grade 9/10&nbsp;<\/b><font size=\"4\">-&nbsp;<\/font>this is excellent condition, minor wear or light scratches.<\/font><\/div><div style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"><font face=\"Georgia\"><b style=\"font-size: 14pt;\">B Grade 8/10&nbsp;<\/b><font size=\"4\">-&nbsp;<\/font>may come with minor discoloration / scratches / minor dings<\/font><\/div><div style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"><font face=\"Georgia\"><b style=\"font-size: 14pt;\">C Grade 6/10<\/b><font size=\"4\">&nbsp;-&nbsp;<\/font>this is generally for people who'd want to save a lot of money and **doesn't**......
```

My code:

```
var html = "<iframe srcdoc = '"+Data+"'></iframe>";
```

This terminates when it encounters (') in "doesn't"(marked in bold in the JSON string above).

I also tried

```
var html = '<iframe srcdoc = \"'+Data+"\'><iframe>';
```

which displays an empty iframe. Also when I logged "Data" and checked in the console log, none of the double quotes in the JSON string were escaped.

How do I have this plain text html code from JSON file executed and displayed in an iframe writing in javascript? I hope this question make sense. Thank you.

Comment: Just escape doesn't `doesn\'t`

Comment: I have no control over that string. It's returned by an api call in a JSON. But is there a way I could get into the string and escape it?

Comment: 1) That is not JSON
2) don't use iframes.
3) select an element, make a local variable for said element, let's call it`ele`, then write it's `innerHTML` like `ele.innerHTML = Data;`

Comment: @StevenStark I wish I didn\'t have to use iframe, but it's a school homework and the spec says I need to. It's actually JSON, I didn't paste the entire JSON file here and didn't paste the entire value of the tag either because it's too long.

Comment: @Navaneeth Actually, no, that's a URLEncoded string of HTML content, there is no JSON there at all. You can verify what is valid JSON at: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @StevenStark oh no, what I have posted does not contain any JSON, it's a value of a JSON file's key is what I meant.

Comment: You likely need to use `decodeUriComponent` described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

so, assuming your code will work after this, `var html = "<iframe srcdoc = '"+decodeURIComponent( Data )+"'></iframe>";` .. that is, assuming that you can write html to the srcdoc attribute like that. I've never tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna show your code (which isn't JSON) on your display just do:

```
const json_to_display = "<font rwr=\"1\" size=\"4\" style=\"font-family:Arial\"><font rwr=\"1\" size=\"4\" style=\"font-family:Arial\"><font rwr=\"1\" size=\"4\" style=\"font-family:Arial\"><font rwr=\"1\" size=\"4\" style=\"font-family:Arial\"><font rwr=\"1\" style=\"font-family: Arial;\"><font rwr=\"1\" style=\"font-family: Arial;\"><div style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"><br><div style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"><font face=\"Georgia\"><b style=\"font-size: 14pt;\">A Grade 9/10&nbsp;<\/b><font size=\"4\">-&nbsp;<\/font>this is excellent condition, minor wear or light scratches.<\/font><\/div><div style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"><font face=\"Georgia\"><b style=\"font-size: 14pt;\">B Grade 8/10&nbsp;<\/b><font size=\"4\">-&nbsp;<\/font>may come with minor discoloration / scratches / minor dings<\/font><\/div><div style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"><font face=\"Georgia\"><b style=\"font-size: 14pt;\">C Grade 6/10<\/b><font size=\"4\">&nbsp;-&nbsp;<\/font>this is generally for people who'd want to save a lot of money and **doesn't**......";

document.getElementById(elementWhereToDisplay).innerHTML = json_to_display; //This will put your code on the element you want(elementWhereToDisplay);
```

Between, you can use `` or " " or ' ' to write strings, the first one will allow you to do it on multiline.

I hope I understood it well and it's gonna work :D

Comment: Actually I wanna get the code executed as html and show the resulting page in the iframe.

Comment: @Navaneeth Why in a iframe? Have you tried on anotherr kind of element?

Comment: It's a school homework and spec says that I need to use iframe. I would have used something else if I could.